# How to get available subnets from AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-vpc

I am trying to create an Application Load Balancer using AWS CLI.
[create-load-balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-load-balancer.html)

The error message is as follows:
`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateLoadBalancer operation: At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified`

So I need to get available subnets from a specific zone (ex: us-east-2).
How can I get the all available subnets using AWS CLI?

Comment: Use the `describe-subnets` command to list all the subnets. Details about the command can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-subnets.html. To get a list of all subnet ids only, run this command: `aws ec2 describe-subnets --query 'Subnets[*].[SubnetId]' --output text`

Comment: Update your question to include the command that you executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a new Application Load Balancer you should use the following CLI Command:

```
aws elbv2 create-load-balancer --name my-load-balancer --subnets SUBNET_1 SUBNET_2
```

You can get the list of available subnets by analyzing your VPC. To do this please follow these steps:

- Open your AWS Console
- Navigate to VPC
- Open Subnets section on the left
- Get the subnets that are linked to your VPC and make sure that you have two subnets in two different availability zones. If you don't have then please create them
- Use these subnets with the above CLI command

If you don't have console access for any reason then use this command to get the list of available subnets from the CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets
```